# How to export output of batch file/Powershell Script in a Excel Spreadsheet

Tags: excel, powershell, batch-file, automation

I have been asked to go around the entire building and document the serial numbers, and system information on all of the PC's in the network. As I was doing it I realized that I could of just wrote a batch file or Powershell Script to do this for me. I typed in the command "wmic bios get serialnumber" and it gave me the serial number for my machine. Is there a way to Get all of the information such as the processor, memory, ip address, and serial number and output it in a excel spreadsheet ? If it can only be exported in a text file that is fine. I would like to save it on my server. I don't know how I can save it all to one text file. I realize that I could have the batch file make a text file of its own with the >> %COMPUTERNAME%.txt command.

Any help or suggestions would be great! 
Thanks!

```
Get-WmiObject win32_processor | Findstr ('Name') | Format-List
$env:COMPUTERNAME | Format-List
wmic bios get serialnumber /Format
Get-WmiObject -Class Win32_ComputerSystem | Findstr ('Model') | Format-List
Get-WmiObject -Class Win32_ComputerSystem | Findstr ('Manufacturer') | Format-List
Get-WmiObject -Class Win32_ComputerSystem | Findstr ('Name') | Format-List
(systeminfo | Select-String 'Total Physical Memory:').ToString().Split(':')[1].Trim() | Format-List
Export-CSV -Path C:\Users\ars001\%COMPUTERNAME%.csv | Format-List
```

Comment: The answer is 'yes', there is a way. Welcome to StackOverflow, we are here to help you troubleshoot and fix script/code issues, but not to write it for you. In PowerShell you can use the `Get-WMIObject` cmdlet to get the same info as you would with `wmic`, and even specify what computer to get that info from. Meanwhile, the `Export-CSV` cmdlet will export your results to a CSV file that will open with Excel by default. The rest is up to you. If you write up a script, and can't get it to work, come on back and post the code/issues, and we'll help you work through them.

Comment: Get-WmiObject win32_processor | Findstr ('Name')
$env:COMPUTERNAME
wmic bios get serialnumber
Get-WmiObject -Class Win32_ComputerSystem | Findstr ('Model')
Get-WmiObject -Class Win32_ComputerSystem | Findstr ('Manufacturer')
Get-WmiObject -Class Win32_ComputerSystem | Findstr ('Name')
(systeminfo | Select-String 'Total Physical Memory:').ToString().Split(':')[1].Trim()

Comment: Sorry I am having issues with the formatting on this site.

Comment: You should really update your question, and not add that as a comment. It's easier to read, and easier to find for people trying to help you

Comment: Please do not post code snippets in comments as they are almost not readable, add them to the question by [editing](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/40746938/edit) your post, applying [proper formatting](http://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting)!

Comment: WMIC can also get all this information if you supply it a list of computer names in a text file.  `WMIC /node:@computers.txt`.  Also with WMIC, you can tell it to `/FORMAT` the output in CSV format.

Comment: I didn't mean for the code snippits to look like that sorry I am new to the website.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, you evidently put in some effort to get the commands to at least gather the info and what classes you'd need for what details, so I'll give you this much...

```
$Computers = Get-Content C:\Path\To\ComputerList.txt
[array]$Results = $Record = Get-WmiObject -Class Win32_ComputerSystem -ComputerName $PC | select Model,Manufacturer,Name,TotalPhysicalMemory
$Results[0] | Add-Member 'Processor' $(Get-WmiObject win32_processor -ComputerName $PC | % Name)
$Results[0] | Add-Member 'SerialNumber' $(Get-WmiObject bios -ComputerName $PC |% serialnumber)
ForEach($PC in $Computers){
    If(!(Test-Connection $PC -Quiet) -or $PC -eq $env:COMPUTERNAME){Continue}
    $Record = Get-WmiObject -Class Win32_ComputerSystem -ComputerName $PC | select Model,Manufacturer,Name,TotalPhysicalMemory
    $Record | Add-Member 'Processor' $(Get-WmiObject win32_processor -ComputerName $PC | % Name)
    $Results += $Record | Add-Member 'SerialNumber' $(Get-WmiObject bios -ComputerName $PC |% serialnumber) -PassThru
}
$Results | Export-Csv c:\Path\To\Output.csv -NoTypeInformation
```

Then you just need to edit the paths, and have a list of computers saved as a text file. If you have the AD module installed you can query AD for that info instead.

Comment: Thank you! I just recently started this script but I have been stuck on a couple of parts!